# Duvida em Calculo de %

Tags: c#, matemática

Alguém saberia me explicar como fazer a seguinte formula? 
Tenho 3 valores: `Valor_Vendido`, `Valor_Minimo_A_Ser_Vendido` e `%_Atingida`.

Exemplo:

Vendi 500 reais e o `Valor_Minimo_A_Ser_Vendido` era para ser 1000 reais, logo eu atingi `50%` em `%_atingida`.

Não precisam me dar de mão beijada o código em C#, gostaria apenas de saber a formula para fazer o mesmo.

Answer (score 7):

Regra de três. É mais uma questão matemática do que problema de C#.

```
var percentual = (valorVendido * 100) / valorMinino;
```

Answer (score 4):

Decorar fórmula é complicado, pois daqui a alguns minutos certamente a esqueceremos.

Melhor é entender o mecanismo, daí nunca esqueceremos como calcular.

A montagem é muito simples:

Pergunta

```
 Se 1000 = 100%, 

    500 = quantos%
```

Vamos montar nossa equação

```
   1000     100
 _______ = _______

   500    quantos
```

Feita a pergunta é só resolver a equação.

Como se trata de uma regra de três simples direta, multiplicamos os valores em cruz, isto é, em X,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

quantos * 1000 = 500 * 100

quantos = (500 * 100)/1000

<sub>que genericamente seria `quantos = (valorVendido * 100) / valorMinino;`</sub>

quantos = 50000/1000

quantos = 50%

Answer (score 2):

Lembre-se, um percentual é uma razão entre dois valores (e portanto, um dividido pelo outro) multiplicada por 100. Utilizando o seu exemplo, você logo descobre quem deve ser dividido por quem; aí é só multiplicar por 100. Isso vale pra C# ou qualquer linguagem de programação.