# Como usar % em Portugol

Tags: matemática, portugol, porcentagem

Tenho a seguinte questão:

> Escreva um algoritmo que calcule o salário de um trabalhador. Serão solicitados do usuário o valor da hora trabalhada, número de horas e o **%** de desconto do INSS. Ao final, imprima o salário líquido do trabalhador.

Comment: vc quer a porcentagem ou o módulo `%` ?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Duvida em Calculo de %](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/199586/duvida-em-calculo-de)

Comment: Obrigado @jbueno.

Conheci a stack ontem pelo podcast Hipster Ponto Tech.

De qualquer forma, obrigado pelo link do Topico.

Comment: De nada, jovem. Seja bem-vindo.

Comment: Parece que a minha interpretação que era um problema de porcentagem está correta. Mas a pergunta era sobre matemática, ou Portugol? Eu respondi sobre Portugol porque era a *tag* colocada na pergunta e estava no título.

Comment: @bigown sobre portugol mesmo, poremos foi acordado regra de lógica multiplicador.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em qualquer cálculo matemático para utilizar o "percentual" é só seguir a lógica de Multiplicar o valor desejado pelo numero do percentual dividido por 100.

**Exemplo:** 15% de 200,00:
`200 * (15 / 100) 
 200 * 0,15 
 30,00`

Pode ser aplicada a qualquer linguagem.

Comment: Obrigado Leonardo.
Muito útil a informação.

Answer (score 5):

Igual em qualquer outra linguagem. Alias igual na matemática.

```
liquido <- valorTotal * (100 - descontoInss) / 100
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Portugol/Discount.ptg).

Comment: Obrigado bigown