# Calcular porcentagem php

Tags: php, matemática

Tenho dois números, um deles é fixo (*1700*) e um vai estar sempre alternando entre *0* e *1700*, eu quero calcular a porcentagem desse numero que esta alternando, por exemplo, quando o numero for *1071* a porcentagem seja igual a *63%*, quando for 1700 seja igual a *100%*!

```
$NumeroFixo = 1700
$Alternado = 1071

$Porcentagem = 63%
```

Como posso fazer isso ?

Comment: Está confuso: `1071 a porcentagem seja igual a 63%, quando for 1700 seja igual a 100%` como assim?

Comment: 1071 é 63% de 1700!

Comment: @FoX É que o exemplo usando números parecidos induz ao erro.

Comment: essa já tem resposta aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/199586/duvida-em-calculo-de/199616#199616

Answer (score 8, accepted):

É mais um problema de matemática do que PHP.

É só fazer uma regra de três e representar no código.

A regra de três é simples, acredito que você já saiba, mas vou deixar a lógica a título de demonstração

```
Se 1700 é 100%, quantos % é 1071?

1700 --- 100
1071 ---  x

Multiplica-se as diagonais e tem-se:

1700x = 1071*100; -> 
1700x = 107100; -> 
x = 107100 / 1700; -> 
x = 63
```

Agora é só trocar estes valores pelos nomes das variáveis e representar a expressão em código.

```
$Porcentagem = ($Alternado * 100) / $NumeroFixo;
```

<sup>**[Veja funcionando no Repl.it](https://repl.it/@jfbueno/ExcitingExtraneousBufflehead)**</sup>

Comment: ah tendi, Obrigado!